# Celery remote worker accessing file

Tags: celery, remote-file-inclusion

I have a function which should take an executable file as argument, execute it and return the result. This function should be run asynchronously so I'm using celery. I want to use multiple computers as workers so each worker should be able to access the executable file. However since the executable files are uploaded by the moderators it's not an option to put a version of each file in each worker by hand. So what would be the best way to handle this?

The only option I could thought of was storing the files in the database. the function should retrieve the file from DB and store it temporarily. Execute it ,remove the file and return the result.

Is this a good approach? Are there any better ways to handle this?

Comment: you can (and should) store it in AWS S3..

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The system is probably going to be used for local use. However I don't understand what's the difference between storing it in AWS and storing it in a local server. Since my function should be able to retrieve the file from the server anyway. My question is how should the files be stored on server and how should the function retrieve them?